# 1С: точка с запятой в запросах

Tags: 1с

Вопрос, как вывести точку с запятой в строке.
Пример:

```
ВЫБРАТЬ ";" ИЗ таблица1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Запрос = Новый Запрос();
Запрос.Текст =  "ВЫБРАТЬ
                |   "";"" КАК Поле1";

Выборка = Запрос.Выполнить().Выбрать();

Выборка.Следующий();

Сообщить(Выборка.Поле1);
```